# How to have excel automatically replace one word with another word?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble finding my answer for this elsewhere. I need to be able to type in a code (ex. CK) and have the cell show "Checking Account" when I press enter. Or SV for Savings Account, RI for Roth IRA, etc. Here is what I have tried:

Conditional Formatting>New Rule>Use Formula> `=$C$25="CK"`

Then the format I input was Number>Custom> "Checking Account"

No matter what I do, it stays "CK." I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to use: `;;;"Checking Account"` to note that you want to change the text to that value. One note: this does not actually change the value, but masks the value to look different.

Comment: Maybe you're looking at spelling corrector? You can modify a dictionary somewhere in the options. But I recommend using VBA over that.

Comment: I would use Autocorrect to replace "Ck" with "Checking Account".

Answer (score 0):

=if(A1=“CK”,”Checking Account”)

Replace A1 with the cell range you want CK to be replaced with Checking Account.

If it’s a range input like A1:A5 or A1:E1
Easiest I could come up with as a suggestion.

Comment: Note: This is to point at specific cell values to make cell value with formula equal to true value output.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, is impossible with an Excel formula: an Excel formula is present in a cell and calculates the value, based mostly from information from another cell.

You are looking for a macro, and I would advise you to check for the `Worksheet_Change` event, something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Value = "CK" Then
  Target.Value = "Checking Account"
  End If
End Sub
```